# Needing a new column to be chosen and print out to an text area using an onchange function with a drop drop down meun

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, textarea, onchange

Ok what I have here is an array that is 6x6 with numbers.  The part that I'm having issues with is I need to use an onchange in the drop down list to only choose the column that is selected. So if I select column 5 it will only display the numbers in that column.  I have spent sometime on line looking for a way to do to this so I'm turning to everyone here.  I am only using java script to create this too

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        // create a var for a 2-D array (6x6)

        var afNumbers = new Array(6)
        var i
        var j

        for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            afNumbers[i] = new Array(6)

        //fill the array by using a nested for loop
        //loop  through each row

        for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //loop through each item in those row
            for (j = 0; j <= 5 ; j++) {
                afNumbers[i][j] = i + j
            }

        }
        //function to print the array in the text area
        function vPrint() {
            var strOut = ""
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                //loop through each item in those row
                for (j = 0; j <= 5 ; j++)
                {
                    strOut += afNumbers[i][j] + "\t"
                }
                strOut += "\r"
            }
            document.getElementById('taOut').value = strOut
        }

        function vDiagonal() {
            var strOut = ""
            for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                //loop through each item in those row
                for (j = 0; j <= 5 ; j++) {
                    if (i == j)
                        strOut += afNumbers[i][j] + "\t"
                    else strOut += "" + "\t"
                }
                strOut += "\r"
            }
            document.getElementById('taOut').value = strOut

            function vColumn()
            {
                if (document.getElementById('PrintMenu').value == "1")
                {
                    document.getElementById('').innerHTML = afNumbers[j] + strOut
                }
            }                      
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm2DArray" style="text-align:center">
        <h2>Two Dimensional Arrays</h2>
        <input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print Array" onclick="vPrint()"/><br /><br />
        <input type="button" id="btnTranspose" value="Print Transpose" /><br /><br />
        <input type="button" id="btnDiagonal" value="Print Diagonal" onclick="vDiagonal()" />
        <h3>Print</h3>
         <select id="PrintMenu" onchange="vColumn()">
            <option value="1">Column 1</option>
            <option value="2">Column 2</option>
            <option value="3">Column 3</option>
            <option value="4">Column 4</option>
            <option value="5">Column 5</option>
       </select>
<br />        
        <textarea id="taOut" rows="40" cols="80"></textarea>        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the error? also, whats the real question?

Comment: There is no error just needing help creating the function to display the column of numbers that you choose from the drop down menu using an onchange function

Answer (score 0):

First off I'm noticing a disconcerting lack of semicolons in your code. Put those after your statements!

You can get the value of the printmenu and store in in a variable.

```
var col = document.getElementById('PrintMenu').value;
```

From there you can loop across the array with that value.

```
afNumbers.forEach(function(entry) {
  document.write(entry[col]);
});
```

That should spit out each of the numbers in the column.

Comment: that is great an all but I need to use an onchange in my drop down line

Comment: @dmbfan42 Okay, so wrap that in a function and call the function with the onclick.